# How to get the datetime of two hours interval?

Tags: ios, swift, datetime

I tried several ways, but I didn't get a workable solution.
I need a two hours interval `datetime` from today to the next five days and the time frame must be morning 7:00 to night 22:00.

What I tried so far is:

```
    let cal = Calendar(identifier: Calendar.Identifier.gregorian)
    for i in 1..<6{
        let date = Date()
        var components = DateComponents()
        components.setValue(i, for: .day)
        let expirationCal = cal.date(byAdding: components, to: date)


        let calendar = NSCalendar.autoupdatingCurrent

        for i  in 0..<12 {

            var  newDateTime = calendar.date(byAdding: Calendar.Component.hour, value: 1, to: expirationCal!)
            let currentHour = calendar.component(.hour, from: newDateTime!)
            let hourInt = Int(currentHour.description)!

            if hourInt >= 8 && hourInt <= 22 {
                print(newDateTime)
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion:

- Calculate start and end date
- Enumerate the dates at full hours from start to end date and filter the even dates in the given range

  ```
  let cal = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
  let startDate = Date()
  let endDate = cal.date(byAdding: .day, value: 5, to: startDate)
  let fullHourComponents = DateComponents(minute: 0, second: 0)

  var dates = [Date]()
  cal.enumerateDates(startingAfter: startDate, matching: fullHourComponents, matchingPolicy: .nextTime) { date, strict, stop in
      if let validDate = date {
          if validDate == endDate { stop = true; return}
          let currentHour = cal.component(.hour, from: validDate)
          if currentHour.isMultiple(of: 2), (7..<23) ~= currentHour {
              dates.append(validDate)
          }
      }
  }
  print(dates)
  ```

Consider that the printed dates are in UTC

Comment: thank you so much. i seem time is starting from to 2:00:00 and ending 16:00:00 but  i looking range  from 8:00:00 to 22:00:00 with two our interval. please help

Comment: Obviously your time zone is  UTC+0600. `2:00:00+00:00`  is the same as `8:00:00+06:00`. Display the date with a date formatter then you get the local date.

Comment: Out of point!  if assign `dates`  into the  local notification for future event.  then is it fire with  UTC+0600 time zone?.

Comment: Probably. Try it out.

Comment: Not my downvote but why are you using startOfDay for today's date as startDate? Btw only even hours are valid?

Comment: @LeoDabus *from today* can –  but does not necessarily – mean *from now*

Comment: OP it is using now as the start date

Comment: @LeoDabus I changed it but now you get also fractional results for the last day.